# rake aborted! uninitialized constant CreateConversationsSummaries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am getting a `rake aborted!
uninitialized constant CreateConversationsSummaries` when running `rake:db migrate`. I am trying to use SQL to aggregate information for the conversations.

My migration:

```
class CreateConversationSummaries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE VIEW conversation_summaries AS
        SELECT c.id,
        s.name as sender_name,
        r.name as recipient_name
        FROM conversations c
        inner join users r on r.id = c.recipient_id
        inner join users s on s.id = c.sender_id
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute 'DROP VIEW conversation_summaries'
  end
end
```

Could it be clashing with the migration I did previously?

```
class CreateConversations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :conversations do |t|
      t.string :sender_id
      t.string :recipient_id
      t.string :subject

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess there is a difference in the name of the migration file vs the name of the class, though I don't recall seeing an uninitialized constant error in that case usually. Check that the name of the migration file is a camel-cased version of the class name contained in it.

Right now there appears to be a difference between the constant being requested `CreateConversationsSummaries` and what is defined in your migration `CreateConversationSummaries`, plural vs. singular conversations.

Comment: Thank you so much. Easy fix and something I definitely won't forget next time.